# Extract tags from DOCX using POI-TL

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx-mailmerge

POI-TL replaces the tags inside DOCX but I can't find any API that can give me a list of tags. Does anyone have experience using POI-TL to achieve this?

I already tried building my own code to find the tags but word transforms tags into multiple runs (sometimes over 5) and so I gave up on writing my own code and started looking into prebuilt open source solutions like POI-TL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Poi-tl API is:

```java
com.deepoove.poi.XWPFTemplate.getElementTemplates()
```

You can visit like this:

```java
new LogProcessor().process(template.getElementTemplates());
```